# Is it true that all sphere bundles are some double of disk bundle?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

Let's consider a smooth sphere bundle over a smooth manifold with structure group is equal to the diffeomorphism group of sphere. Then, can we say that this is a double of some disk bundle? Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. If a sphere bundle is the double of a disk bundle, then it has a section. You get counterexamples by considering unit sphere bundles of vector bundles with nonvanishing Euler class.

Comment: More precisely, it is not hard to see that a sphere bundle is the double of a disc bundle if and only if it has a section.

Comment: @Neil Is it clear that you have a strict double, that is, are both halves automatically isomorphic? Then I guess, another equivalent formulation is that the sphere bundle is a fibrewise suspension of another sphere bundle. And somehow this seems to imply that all sphere bundles with a section are linear, but that seems to be too strong a conclusion.

Comment: @SebastianGoette I guess I was just thinking about the linear case, I agree that there might be more to say in general.

Comment: Here's a spherical fibration version of the statement you're after: If a spherical fibration is an unreduced  fiberwise suspension of another one, then that fibration comes equipped with two sections which are vertically homotopic. Conversely, if $E \to B$ is a spherical fibration equipped with two sections, represented by a fiberwise map $s:B\times S^0 \to E$, then in a certain metastable range the fibration fiberwise desuspends relative to $s$.   This is explained in the paper:


Klein, John R.; Williams, E. Bruce Homotopical intersection theory. I. Geom. Topol. 11 (2007), 939–977.

Answer (score 6):

The connected double cover of $S^1$ (boundary of the Möbius strip) is an $S^0$ bundle that is not the double of the unique $0$-disc bundle over $S^1$.